# How to view all the HTTP Traffic Information with Webservice client tool

Tags: http, rest, web

I am using a Browser Rest Client to execute Webservice calls

My query is , is it possible to view Information like , to what Server the (The IP Address of the server ) the web service call is hit to ??

Currently i am using HttpFox with Firefox , with it i am getting only the basic information like the Request Data .

Please let me know if this possible or not ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Try [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks i tried that , this is also behaving same as HttpFox , i mean no server information . (to which the web service call is being hit )